# Как получить все элементы компонента Vue3?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Код: main.js

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
createApp(App).mount('#app')
```

Код App.vue:

```
<template>
  <div>Элемент 1</div>
  <div>Элемент 2</div>
</template>

<script>
import { onMounted, getCurrentInstance } from "vue";
export default {
  setup() {
    // В обработчике надо получить все элементы <template>
    onMounted(() => {
      console.log(getCurrentInstance().ctx);
      // Это работает если есть один корневой элемент
      // console.log(getCurrentInstance().ctx.$el);
    });
  },
};
</script>
```

`ctx.$el` возвращает корневой элемент `<template>`, только в таком варианте:

```
<template>
<div>
  <div>Элемент 1</div>
  <div>Элемент 2</div>
</div>
</template>
// ...
console.log(getCurrentInstance().ctx.$el) // <div>...</div>
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue3-getcurrentinstance-children-of55r?file=/src/App.vue)

Возможно ли получить список элементов без привязки `ref="refElement"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оказывается, есть такое свойство `subTree`, которое содержит все фрагменты компонента:

```js
getCurrentInstance().subTree.children.map(({ el }) => el)
// => [element, ...]
```

Вот только в документации я ничего не нашел.